# deauthenticated due to local deauth request HOSTAPD

Tags: linux, wifi, hostapd, hotspot

i have set AP in respberry pi 2 model B with TP-LINK Dongle,and the TL-WN772N 
now the problem is that when i try to connect with my respberry pi dongle it's throw an error:

***wpa_sm_step() called recursively.***

***IEEE 802.11:deauthenticated due to local deauth request.***

and what in my hostapd.conf file has:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=SRG
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa=2
auth_algs=1
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
```

and when i removed its security , then it works fine but here in my scenario i need security ? can somebody tell me how can i over come this issue ?
any help will be appreciated...**Thanks**

Comment: can anybody evaluate this problem  ??

Comment: Are you still having problems with this? [This kind of maybe solved my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38173266/344286) but I'm not sure if it was that or adding the [debug mode to my hostpapd.conf](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/hostapd/hostapd.conf)